# Close popup window without click button

Tags: android, popupwindow

I don't want to button for closing pop-up window in Android. I just press the screen than pop-up should close. It works only button click If I click close button then it close but I don't want any button in my popup window I just want click anywhere in the screen then it should be close.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btn1, btn2;
private QuickAction quick;
private PopupWindow window;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1_Click);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(btn2_Click);
    ActionItem itm1 = new ActionItem(1, "Item1", null);
    ActionItem itm2 = new ActionItem(2, "Item2", null);
    quick = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.VERTICAL);
    quick.addActionItem(itm1);
    quick.addActionItem(itm2);
    quick.setOnActionItemClickListener(quick_Clicked);
}

private OnClickListener btn1_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        quick.show(v);
    }

};

private OnClickListener btn2_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
          window = new PopupWindow(layout, 500, 400, true);
          window.showAtLocation(layout,17, 0, 0);
          Button btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonclose);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                window.dismiss();
            }

          });
    }


};

private QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener quick_Clicked = new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(QuickAction source, int pos, int actionId) {
        if (actionId == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item 1 was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (actionId == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item 2 was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Here this is my popup. What kind of changes is enough for me. Should I changes popup class?

```
public class PopupWindows {
protected Context mContext;
public PopupWindow mWindow;
protected View mRootView;
protected Drawable mBackground = null;
protected WindowManager mWindowManager;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param context Context
 */
public PopupWindows(Context context) {
    mContext    = context;
    mWindow     = new PopupWindow(context);
    mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    mWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                mWindow.dismiss();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
}

/**
 * On dismiss
 */
protected void onDismiss() {        
}

/**
 * On show
 */
protected void onShow() {       
}


/**
 * On pre show
 */
protected void preShow() {
    if (mRootView == null) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("setContentView was not called with a view to display.");

    onShow();

//  if (mBackground == null) 
//      mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
//else 
//      mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    mWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //      mWindow.setTouchable(true);
//  mWindow.setFocusable(true);
//  mWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    mWindow.setContentView(mRootView);
}

/**
 * Set background drawable.
 * 
 * @param background Background drawable
 */
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
    mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}

/**
 * Set content view.
 * 
 * @param root Root view
 */
public void setContentView(View root) {
    mRootView = root;

    mWindow.setContentView(root);
}

/**
 * Set content view.
 * 
 * @param layoutResID Resource id
 */
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    setContentView(inflator.inflate(layoutResID, null));
}

/**
 * Set listener on window dismissed.
 * 
 * @param listener
 */
public void setOnDismissListener(PopupWindow.OnDismissListener listener) {
    mWindow.setOnDismissListener(listener);  
}

/**
 * Dismiss the popup window.
 */
public void dismiss() {
    mWindow.dismiss();
}
```

**Popup.xml:**

*It looks ok ı will delete close button. If ı succes to close without close button for my popupwindow*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="1000dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.09"
    android:src="@drawable/karisikwaffle" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a popupWindow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonclose"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you're looking for a way to have the popup auto-close after a certain duration, I posted a way to do that in the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919348/android-making-toast-clickable/23818846#23818846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private OnClickListener btn2_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
          window = new PopupWindow(layout, 500, 400, true);

         // window.setTouchable(true);
         // window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
          window.setBackgroundDrawable (new BitmapDrawable());
         // window.setFocusable(false);
          window.setOutsideTouchable(true); 
          window.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
              public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      window.dismiss(); 
                      return true;
                      }
                  return false; 
                  } 
              }); 
          window.showAtLocation(layout,17, 0, 0);

          Button btn = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonclose);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                window.dismiss();
            }

          });

    }


};
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer actually introduces a bug that intercepts your click listener if your popup has a list view. This means that clicking on the listview/expandablelistview will dismiss the dialog. You actually don't need to set the touch interceptor.

So the code snippet would look like:

```
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

that's it!

if you still wanted to have the touch intercepted (no reason), then you should do something like this:

```
window.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() { 
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { 
       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          window.dismiss();
          boolean consumedEvent = true;
          if (view.hasOnClickListeners()) {
              consumedEvent = view.onTouchEvent(event);
          } 
        return consumedEvent; 
    } 
    return false;    
  } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.setTouchable(true);
window.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() 
{ 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    { 
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        { 
            window.dismiss(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false;    
    } 
});
```

BUNU window.showAtLocation in Altina koy.